# SSH to a server with multiple reverse DNS entries

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, reverse-dns, a-record, cloudflare

While SSHing into my server with an RSA key, I get this message:

> Address 255.100.236.105 <sup>1</sup> maps to a1.example.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!

Even though I get this error, I am still able to SSH into the machine.

I examined the DNS and figured out the issue.  This server has lots of vhosts, so we have multiple A records for the same IP address.

For example:

> A a1.example.com 255.100.236.105
>   A ssh.example.com 255.100.236.105

(there are a few more that point to the same IP)

I am trying to SSH to `ssh.example.com`, and I am getting the above error.  How do I get SSH to realize that the IP has multiple domain names that point to it?

**NOTE**: I can't ssh to `a1.example.com` because that subdomain is going through CloudFlare's proxy.

**UPDATE**: I tested this on two computers.  One gave me that error, one did not.  Why would that be?

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is a fake IP, I made up.  I'm not sure if it really points anywhere.</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sshd warning, “POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!” for failed reverse DNS](http://serverfault.com/q/436913/152073).

Comment: Have you tried adding the reverse DNS entry for ssh.example.com to your hosts file, since DNS looks there first?

Comment: @NickW: Yeah, I guess I could do that.  I just hope our IP address never changes :-)

Comment: @NickW: That did get rid of the error :-D  I guess that's a good solution :-)

Comment: Let me put that in an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the reverse DNS name for `ssh.example.com` in your hosts file, that will usually be the first response returned by DNS.

Comment: Entries in `/etc/hosts` will not "always" be the first response returned by DNS. Specifically, if `dns` is before `hosts` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` your resolver should return the DNS result (if one exists) before ever looking at the hosts file. In any case, this is a pretty dirty hack: the *Right Thing* would be to fix the broken reverse DNS (or disable the DNS check if you really don't care).

Comment: This is a dirty hack, but how would he set up multiple RDNS entries for the same IP to always return the correct answer? I'll change the always though.

Comment: @voretaq7: So, how do I fix the DNS?  I have multiple A names for the same IP.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You make the PTR record match the hostname you SSH into, and you always SSH into the machine with that specific hostname. Or you disable the reverse DNS check.

Comment: @voretaq7: The server has `UseDNS no`.  And it doesn't seem like CloudFlare lets me set PTR records.